# How to find if file has been imported in Access database or created within it?

Tags: ms-access-2010

In my access database there is a dataset which I need to know how it has been created. I tried to backtrack and reached to a table for which I am not able to find any source data. I am pretty much sure that it has been imported from some where. I checked in "View" option there is not "SQL" view for that table. It only has "Datasheet" view and "Design View".

In access database is there any way to check that whether a file has been imported or has been created using SQL query within access database? Is there any "flag" raised or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

No. Once data is persisted in a table, that's it.

If you need further info, you can have a Timestamp field with a default value of:

```
Now()
```

or, if a higher resolution than one second is needed:

```
Date() + Timer() / 86400
```

or another custom field where you record session info as you like during the import or creation of data.